# Console input cannot be read when c++ Android NDK app is build as executable

Tags: android, android-ndk, stdin

For testing purposes I'm running an Android NDK application as "console" app. I've built the app as an executable file(BUILD_EXECUTABLE in Android.mk), pushed it to the device's data/local/tmp dir, and executed it.

Console output is working as expected (with e.g. std::cout).
When I try to get console input (e.g. std::cin.get, getchar(),...), the application blocks (which is also expected). However, I cannot find a way to send the input to the app. Ideally, I would like to do this from another adb terminal.

I already tried to open a new shell and send input to `/proc/pid/fd/0` and `/dev/pts/0`. The input I send is displayed in the shell from which the application was started, but the application is not registering this and keeps blocking. 
I had the same issue when I redirected stdin to a file. I could write to the file  and read from it from another shell window, but the application was still blocking as if there would be no input to read.

The simplest version of the code I was using was just to read console input and write it back to the terminal:

```
int main() {
    std::string in;
    std::cin >> in;
    std::cout << "I typed: " << in << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Then I started a new terminal window and typed e.g.:

```
adb shell "echo 'someinput\r\n'>/proc/pid/fd/0"
```

The first shell window where the application was started got updated with the input, but the application still kept blocking as if it had no input.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Last I looked, commands launched from ADB may be "interactive" (stdin comes from ADB over USB) or non-interactive (stdin comes from /dev/null).  I think only plain "adb shell" is interactive; "adb shell <command>" is not.  This makes it difficult for a host-side program to drive the operation of a command.  You may want to create a named pipe and dup2() that onto stdin.

Comment: @fadden you were right. I tried named pipes among the first things, but it didn't work properly. After your suggestion I looked up pipes once again and I've found out that previously I tried to read from both ends of pipes which caused blocking on both sides. Now i've fixed the code and it works. 
Thank you.